# How to use Message Selectors to filter messages In JMS

Tags: java, jms

I have ejb-jar.xml which contain `<message-selector> destinationInstance IN(a', 'b','c')</message-selector>.`

How we can implement message selector in standalone java program.

`JMSMessageListener` has been registered on queue and whenever there is message on queue , `onMessage` method of listener will be called.

I Have Try this.? Does It work...

public void messageSelector() {

```
List<String> url=StCotants.getUrls();   

    for(String obj:url){

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(obj);

        System.out.println(factory);

        try{
            Connection connection = factory.createConnection();

            connection.start();

            Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 

             Queue queue = session.createQueue("queue");  

             MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue,"destinationInstance IN('a', 'b','c')");

             XyzMDBClient xyzClientlistener=new XyzMDBClient();

             consumer.setMessageListener(xyzClientlistener);

        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Back in time I was looking for examples on how to use message selectors and I found this site very usefull: [How to use Message Selectors to filter messages](https://timjansen.github.io/jarfiller/guide/jms/selectors.xhtml)

Very concise article about what selectors are and how to use them.

> Message Selectors allow you to filter the messages that a MessageConsumer will receive. The filter is a relatively complex language that mimics the syntax of an SQL WHERE clause. The selector can use all message headers and properties for filtering, but can not use the message content.
>   Selectors are mostly useful for Topics that broadcast a very large number of messages to its subscribers.
>
> They way selectors work depends on the destination type:
>
> *On ***Queues***, only messages that match the selector will be returned. Others stay in the queue (and thus can be read by a MessageConsumer with different selector).
>
> *On ***Topics***, messages that do not match the selector will be ignored as if they have not been published.
>   In order to create a selection, you need to pass it to the createConsumer or createDurableSubscriber invocation:

Code examples:

```
    Session session = ...
MessageConsumer consumer1 = session.createConsumer(queue, 
                       "(releaseYear < 1980) OR (releaseYear > 1989)");

MessageConsumer consumer2 = session.createConsumer(queue, 
                       "(releaseYear BETWEEN 1980 AND 1989) AND title LIKE 'Michael%'");

MessageConsumer consumer3 = session.createConsumer(queue, 
                       "(releaseYear = 1982) OR (title = 'Thriller')");

MessageConsumer consumer4 = session.createDurableConsumer(queue, 
                       "title IN ('Off the wall', 'Thriller', 'Bad')");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a consumer, you can mention the selector as second argument
session.createConsumer(queue,"destinationInstance IN('a', 'b','c')")
session.setMessageListener(...)